# Import .ics Feed Into Outlook "My Calendar"

Tags: outlook, icalendar

This might not be the right place to ask this, but I am trying to automatically update an Outlook user's personal calendar with events from a site.  Outlook's "Internet Calendar Subscription" adds the events from an .ics feed to a separate calendar (under "Other Calendars").  I can import the .ics manually via File -> Open -> Import -> Import an iCalendar (.ics) or vCalendar file (.vcs) -> "Import items into your calendar"  How do I import an .ics feed into the personal calendar automatically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot 'import' automatically - that is entirely a user action.

If the user decides to 'subscribe' to the calendar, then it will refresh automatically at whatever intervals the calendar application and the user specify.

Import:
a once off action, goes into the calendar specified by the user, usually the default or main calendar. (Some apps seem to make it a new calendar anyway- thunderbird?)   No updates unless the user deletes and re-imports or modifies.   Think of this as an aid to the user so they do not have to manually create the events in their calendar.  They can modify these events themselves

Subscribe:
This maintains a separate calendar in the calendar application and is refreshed at intervals determined by the calendar application.  Thus updates will be made.  User cannot change these events.   Usually the calendar app allows one to click calendars on/off.   Has great use for saying keeping one's personal calendar and overlaying your partners calendar, the kids, the yoga club schedule, the countries public holidays, the school term calendar, phase of the moon or whatever takes the users fancy and being able to click these non main calendars off easily to see a clean uncluttered view.

Comment: I need the events to be automatically refreshed in the "default or main calendar", not a separate shared calendar.

Comment: I may be wrong (would be interested to know) however I don't believe that's possible unless you have an app with update rights.

Comment: I am not familiar with "update rights" What are you referring to?

Comment: I simply mean authorisation by whatever calendar app the individual uses.  eg: google has an api that allows permitted other apps to update a users calendar.  One cannot simply overwrite entries in an individual's personal calendar.